# How do computational programs decide how many virtual orbitals to compute?

Tags: computational-chemistry, orbitals, theoretical-chemistry

How do computational programs decide how many virtual orbitals to compute? For example, a Gaussian job of benzene at the TD-DFT B3LYP/3-21G level of theory calculates from 42 electrons a total of 66 orbitals. Why not 65 or 67? Is there any significance to the number it to stop at?

Comment: The amount and kind of atoms in your molecule together with the selected basis set determine the number of orbitals and you can determine how many orbitals will be used by looking at the basis set definition. Larger basis sets can improve the accuracy of your calculation but it comes with an increased computational cost.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The basis functions you use describe a space within which your orbitals are vectors. If you have $N$ basis functions this space is $N$-dimensional, and in a $N$-dimensional space you can have at most $N$ vectors which are linearly independent, thus you can have at most $N$ orbitals. In the above example, the 3-21G basis set you are using has 66 basis functions, 9 on each carbon and 2 on each hydrogen, and $(6 \cdot 9) + (6 \cdot 2) = 66$, so you can describe at most 66 orbitals.

Comment: How do you know how many basis functions are on each atom?

Comment: That's what 3-21G implies - split valence with no polarisation functions

Comment: If larger basis sets are used the virtual space becomes a problem. There are (iirc) some methods that try to work around this by actually truncating it. Note that it's still the methods and not the program that accomplish that.

Comment: I did start writing in the answer that when a plane wave basis set you would never calculate all the virtuals, but thought that a complication too far. And even in a Gaussian basis set if you are just finding the ground state by the normal diagonalisation method it is easy to avoid calculating (all of) the virtuals, it's just as you get them more or less for free nobody bothers.