# Orbitals in benzene and other delocalised structures

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory

I've read that molecular orbital theory demands that if there are $n$ orbitals prior to some event like bond formation, there should be $n$ orbitals after this event.

Does this hold even in structures with conjugation like benzene, benzoic acid and so on? If so, then does the formation of benzene itself result in a chromic shift?

Comment: Chromic shift from what?

Comment: Yes, if there are a total of N atomic orbitals in the carbon and hydrogen atoms, then there should be a total of N molecular orbitals in benzene, benzoic acid, etc. As @Andrew mentioned, I'm not sure what you mean by "chromic shift."

Comment: @Andrew from the formation of benzene from say 1,3-cyclohexa diene similar to the seen when a benzenediazonium cation and, say for instance, phenol react to form 4-(phenyldiazenyl)phenol

Comment: Apart from the Chromic shift thing, which I don't understand, this is close to a duplicate of https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/164346/how-do-computational-programs-decide-how-many-virtual-orbitals-to-compute/164352